# Get current line when some previous lines was collapsed in my own eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, text-editor

Im trying to get the current line of keyboard cursor.

```
StyledText styledText = (StyledText) getAdapter(Control.class);
styledText.addCaretListener(event -> {
    try {
        IDocument document = getDocumentProvider().getDocument(getEditorInput());
        // This is the current line
        int currentLine = document.getLineOfOffset(event.caretOffset);

    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
    }
});
```

But the method getLineOfOffset doesn't work when some previous lines are collapsed. The event.caretOffset change if the document was collapsed.

Im tryed to use this code:

```
ISelectionProvider selectionProvider = ((ITextEditor)editor).getSelectionProvider();
ISelection selection = selectionProvider.getSelection();
if (selection instanceof ITextSelection) {
    ITextSelection textSelection = (ITextSelection)selection;
    return textSelection.getStartLine();
}
```

But this last code return the old line selected. I think the event of addCaretListener executes before the change line (not sure).

How can I get the current line even the document was collapsed in addCaretListener event?

Comment: The event.caretOffset is different to document collapsed and document not collapsed for the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your editor is using `ProjectionViewer` as the source viewer you can
use the `ITextViewerExtension5` `widgetOffset2ModelOffset` method:

```
ISourceViewer sourceViewer = getSourceViewer(); // Get your SourceViewer

StyledText styledText = sourceViewer.getTextWidget();

int docOffset = 0;
if (sourceViewer instanceof ITextViewerExtension5) {
    ITextViewerExtension5 extension = (ITextViewerExtension5)sourceViewer;
    docOffset = extension.widgetOffset2ModelOffset(styledText.getCaretOffset());
} 
else {
    int offset = sourceViewer.getVisibleRegion().getOffset();
    docOffset = offset + styledText.getCaretOffset();
}

IDocument document = sourceViewer.getDocument();

int currentLine = document.getLineOfOffset(docOffset);
```

(adapted from the JDT JavaEditor).